# Where does the viscocity solution concept come from?

Tags: numerical-methods, optimal-control, hamilton-jacobi-equation, viscosity-solutions

I understand that viscocity solutions are well suited for solving Optimal control problems involving Hamilton–Jacobi–Bellman equations.

But how did the inventors get the idea for viscocity solutions? How did they know that these would probably fit the problem setting well?